# Scope ordering by reverse order not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scopes

I have my scope:

```
scope :latest_photos, -> {order(:created_at).reverse_order.limit(10)}
```

It's supposed to put the latest photos in first place right? Well photos get put on the last place instead.

I've also tried:

```
scope :latest_photos, -> {order('created_at DESC').limit(10)}
```

but nothing. Any ideas? Thanks!

### EDIT

Something is not working here:

**routes.rb**

```
get 'spots/ultimos' => 'photos#latest
```

**photos controller**

```
def latest
        @categories = Category.all
        @zones = Zone.all
        @photos = Photo.latest_photos
        @action = 'general'
        @photos = Photo.paginate(:page => params[:page])
        render :index
    end
```

**model**

```
  scope :latest_photos, -> {order(created_at: :desc).limit(10)}
```

Comment: What do you get with `Photo.latests_photos.to_sql`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def latest
    @categories = Category.all
    @zones = Zone.all
    @photos = Photo.latest_photos
    @action = 'general'
    @photos = Photo.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    render :index
end
```

You have assigned `@photos` variable twice, second assignment overrides the previous one. Instead do:

```
def latest
    @categories = Category.all
    @zones = Zone.all
    @photos = Photo.latest_photos
    @action = 'general'
    render :index
end
```

The actual value to be assigned depends on what you want to achieve here. Since action is called latest and you have limit in your scope, I have assumed you don't need pagination here.

Comment: But then, how can I paginate photos? I need to. Like this?

 @photos = Photo.latest_photos.paginate(:page => params [:page]) ?

Comment: Yep, that worked, I was overriding photos , what I did in order to preserve pagination is:  @photos = Photo.latest_photos.paginate(:page => params [:page])

Comment: @Gibson - If you want pagination, than this is correct.